# Regular Expression for specific numbers

Tags: regex

I am trying to pull out of a report two specific numbers `0103` and `0101`.  How do I do this?

```
^.*\b(0101|0103)\b.*$
```

It only gave me `0101`.

Comment: Are the numbers part of a larger string and do you need the whole line or just that number on its own?

Comment: How are you pulling the numbers out?  What does the input string look like?

Comment: This regex should work unless both numbers appear in the same string - then it will only find the last one that occurs because the first `.*` has already matched everything before it.

Answer (score 3):

This regex should work:

```
\b010[13]\b
```

Comment: Glad to know it worked out, can you mark the answer as accepted by clicking on tick mark on top-left of my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this :

```
((?:0101|0103))
```

without the ^ and the $-> If you keep both char, then the program will find the whole string, and look in only one time.
Then, you need to do a loop to catch each element.

Hope it helps